# 'Class not found' when using namespaces in PHPUnit

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

I'm new to PHPUnit and am having some trouble setting it up to access my PHP files. The directory structure I'm using for my app is this:

```
./phpunit.xml

./lib/Application/
  -> Dir1/File1.php (namespace = Application\Dir1)
  -> Dir1/File2.php
  -> Dir2/File1.php (namespace = Application\Dir2)

./tests/Application/Tests
  -> Test1.php (namespace = Application\Tests)
  -> Test2.php
```

In my PhpUnit.xml, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit verbose="false">
  <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="Application">
          <directory>./tests/Application/Tests</directory>
      </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <logging>
       <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
       <log type="json" target="/tmp/phpunit-logfile.json"/>
  </logging>
  <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./lib</directory>
        </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

And in one of my test files, I open with:

```
namespace Application\Tests;

use Application\Dir1\File1;

class MyTest extends File1 {}
```

But it keeps on saying:

> Class 'Application\Dir1\File1' not found

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How do you load Dir1/File1.php from your test file? `use` statement doesn't mean that you should not require necessary files.

Comment: I tried using a bootstrap file which references an Autoload.php - but I wasn't sure what functionality to use to include all necessary files. I also thought PHPUnit.xml would automatically include the required files in the `<filter>` node. Is that not the case?

Comment: Just try to put `require_once` statement in the beginning and it should work.

Comment: So for every test I write, I have to `require_once` every file? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of using namespaces to autoload  files? Seems a bit hacky...

Comment: You acan use this approach: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Again, this defeats the purpose of namespaces in 5.3. I want it to be PSR-0 compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you use `use`, you still have to include the file, either by using `include`, `require`, `include_once`, or `require_once`, or by using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to include the file, like so:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
    include '\lib\\' . $class . 'php';
});
```

When you then try to use `Application\Dir1\File1` the script will automatically run `include '\lib\Application\Dir1\File1.php'`

Comment: You're right. But I want to get away from manually specifying the dependencies and move towards a more automated solution. My solution uses a way of doing that - but thanks anyway :)

Comment: How is your way more automated? It looks pretty much the same, just with more overhead.

Comment: Well, for one, this isn't handling directory separators (for different OS's), whereas the more comprehensive class does. But you did point me in the right direction - so it's only fair I mark this as the accepted solution.

Comment: Good point on the DS. Although you can simply that with `str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);`.

Answer (score 28):

If you installed PHPUnit using Composer then you can use Composers autoloader. The easiest way to do so would be to add:

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-0":{
        "your-app-directory":""
    }
}
```

to composer.json

Comment: I installed phpunit with composer and this does not solve the problem. Even using psr-4 and even swapping "your-app-directory" and ""

Comment: @Leggy7 can you send me what your trying to use

Comment: please mention to use 'composer dump-autoload'

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
I'm using composer as well and the only thing that solved it for me was the following:

1. add to your composer.json file in the autoload section a class map section with your root namespace

   ```
   "autoload":  {
           "classmap": ["namespaceRoot/"]
   }
   ```
2. execute `composer dump-autoload` command in order to recreate your autoload files (with all the class mappings!)

Comment: the composer dump-autoload solved my 1 hour headache :D, thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

I found this really useful [class autoloader](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634) by Jonathan Wage which allows PHPUnit tests to access namespaces from different directories. In my bootstrap.php, I just specified the location and associated module namespace:

```
require_once 'SplClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Application', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib');
$classLoader->register();
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning bootstrap.php. That's where
 my setup loads out custom autoader.

Comment: I did exactly this, but it cannot find the classes then. It also seems to not recursively go into all directories.