# Class not found only when using PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm working on testing with a Symfony2 (2.7.3) app and a page controller is failing to load a class *only when a request is sent from PHPUnit (4.8.6)*.

The test looks like this:

```
//AppBundle/Tests/Controller/PagesAvailableTest.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PagesAvailableTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testpages()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', '/contact'); // Throws the error
    }
}
```

and throws this error when run with `$ phpunit -c app/`:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppBundle\Entity\ContactMessage' not found in ***SymfonyRoot***/src/AppBundle/Controller/ContactController.php on line 28

When called through the browser, the page loads as expected. When called using `$ curl -I http://localhost/contact`, the page's status is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

I've looked at other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719293/class-not-found-when-using-namespaces-in-phpunit) that discuss problems with autoloading - but the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html) suggest that classes should be autoloading without problems:

> Just like in your real application - autoloading is automatically enabled via the bootstrap.php.cache file (as configured by default in the app/phpunit.xml.dist file).

```
<!-- app/phpunit.xml.dist -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--<php>-->
        <!--In my experimentation, I uncommented this and tinkered with 
            a few values. After having no luck, I commented it out again. -->
        <!--<server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="." />-->
    <!--</php>-->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

How can I load these classes when using PHPUnit?

Comment: Your OP states you run `phpunit -c app/`.  The `-c` option takes a file, not a directory.  Perhaps you should be running `phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist`.

Comment: I appreciate the tip - but running `phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist` doesn't seem to change anything. I am running `phpunit -c app/` because it was the suggested command in [the docs I refer to](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html).

Comment: Curious on those docs, I didn't know (and am dubious) that `-c` takes a directory.  Try running `composer run-script post-update-cmd` to update the bootstrap cache file?

Comment: Nope, I edited my comment.  Try again with composer.

Comment: `$ composer run-script post-update-cmd` ran successfully - but I still get the same error.

Comment: I'm expecting to find `AppBundle\Entity\ContactMessage` in your `bootstrap.php.cache`.  I can't remember if that's a binary file or not, but try `grep` to find if your Entity is listed.

Comment: @bishop - phpunit -c app will work just fine.  And no the entities will not be in the bootstrap file, only common core classes.  The bootstrap file also pulls in the autoload file.  I'm guessing there is a problem with the test configuration.  But I can't see the problem from what has been posted.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, learn something new daily!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I embarrassingly overlooked a critical detail: My application is running on a different PHP interpreter than my `PATH` environment variable points to.

When I ran `$ phpunit -c app/`, it used my OS's default PHP (5.5.20) - my site is running on PHP 5.6.10 as provided by MAMP.

I was able to get around this by providing my own path to the correct PHP interpreter when invoking PHPUnit:

`$ /path/to/correct/php phpunit -c app/`