# Writing PHPUnit test for a class which extends another class produces a 'Class not found' error

Tags: php, oop, testing, phpunit, fatal-error

What I have:

1. `WPKit/Module/AbstractFunctions.php` Abstract Class;
2. `wp-content/themes/mytheme/modules/quiz/Functions.php`:

   ```
   use WPKit\Module\AbstractFunctions;
   class Functions extends AbstractFunctions { ... }
   ```
3. `wp-content/themes/mytheme/tests/quiz/QuizFunctionsTest.php`:

   ```
   require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../modules/quiz/Functions.php";

   class QuizFunctionsTest extends TestCase {
       public function testGetQuizByID() {
           # some code
       }
   }
   ```

When running `phpunit QuizFunctionsTest.php`, it gives me the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class '%path%\AbstractFunctions' not found in %path%/modules/quiz/Functions.php on line 18`

I tried `require_once` the missing class but it didn't help. Outside the test class my code works just fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please provide more info - 1. How do you run it? 2. How do you import `AbstractFunctions` inside this `.../modules/quiz/Functions.php`?

Comment: @AlexMozharov I've extended the question which should answer your questions

Comment: Thanks, I see now that you using namespaces. I think this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719293/class-not-found-when-using-namespaces-in-phpunit

Comment: you can also find some help here https://stackoverflow.com/q/25219764/576767 but it's hard to tell really, it depends on what autoloader system you are using, and the configuration of your phpunit suites. generally you would specify a bootstrap file for phpunit, that would include vendor/autoload.php

Comment: It seems I couldn't get it to work because it was a WordPress setup so what I did was install PHPUnit via wget and use WP-CLI to scaffold theme-tests, then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TL;DR: It seems I couldn't get it to work because it was a WordPress setup so what I did was install PHPUnit via `wget` and use WP-CLI to scaffold theme-tests, then it worked like a charm.*

---

First I installed the PHPUnit from terminal inside my theme directory:

```
wget -O phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.phar
chmod +x phpunit
```

Next I installed WP-CLI:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
chmod +x wp-cli.phar
sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

Next setting up the test suite:

```
wp scaffold theme-tests your-theme-slug
```

Also make sure you have `svn` installed.

In my case (and I found some mention it, too) I had to delete `/tmp/wordpress` and `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib` and re-run the previous command twice because the script somehow didn't download everything.

Notice that you'll have a separate WordPress setup in `/tmp/wordpress`. In my primary WordPress setup I use WPKit library which is stored in WordPress root near `wp-content` so I had to copy it to `/tmp/wordpress`, otherwise my PHPUnit tests couldn't find WPKit files which were included in the classes I had to test.

So when you run `wp scaffold` it creates `bin` directory in your theme root. Run the following command from your theme root in order to install the test suite:

```
bin/install-wp-tests.sh <test-database-name> <user> <password> <host> <wordpress-version>
```

In my case it looked like:

```
bin/install-wp-tests.sh wp_test root '' localhost latest
```

Be sure to use **empty** database because running PHPUnit clears the database every time so you may lose your data.

After all these actions just run PHPUnit and you should be fine:

```
./phpunit
```

It runs tests in `your-theme/tests` directory. By default it ignores the default test file so use it to make your own simple tests to check everything works.

Whew.

---

> Sources:
>
> - https://www.kirstencassidy.com/testing-wordpress-plugins-wp-cli-phpunit/
> - https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html
> - https://wp-cli.org/#installing
> - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/automated-testing-wordpress-plugins-phpunit/

---